# Errors building R-packages for conda

Tags: r, anaconda, readline, ncurses, conda

I am having a tough time installing R-packages that are not available in the Anaconda repositories. My attempts so far can be found here [How to install R-packages not in the conda repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652015/how-to-install-r-packages-not-in-the-conda-repositories).

Currently, I am trying to build the R-package `rafalib` for `conda` by following the instructions from [this article](https://www.continuum.io/content/conda-data-science) under the heading *Building a conda R package*.

The first part works fine.

```
conda skeleton cran rafalib
```

Out:

```
Tip: install CacheControl to cache the CRAN metadata
Fetching metadata from http://cran.r-project.org/
Writing recipe for rafalib
Done
```

The build command runs into errors

```
conda build r-rafalib
```

Out:

```
Removing old build environment
Removing old work directory
BUILD START: r-rafalib-1.0.0-r3.2.2_0
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: .
Error:  Packages missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - r 3.2.2*
  - r-rcolorbrewer
```

I have `r 3.2.2`-64bit installed via `conda` and it runs without problems. I also already have `r-colorbrewer` installed via `conda` and I can use that package without issues in R. Why am I getting these errors when trying to build a `conda` package?

I am on Linux (Antergos, an Arch derivative) with kernel 4.4.5-1-ARCH.

---

**UPDATE 2015/04/19**

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36653411/2166823), I found out that I could include the dependencies by building them separately in the same directory as the package I want to install. That didn't work for me, but I also read that I can include a channel in the build command with `-c`, just as when installing. So now I do:

```
conda build -c r r-rafalib
```

This gets passed all the dependency problems, but after fetching, extracting and linking packages, it fails. Here is the end of the error message.

```
Removing old work directory
Source cache directory is: /home/joel/anaconda2/conda-bld/src_cache
Downloading source to cache: rafalib_1.0.0.tar.gz
Downloading http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rafalib_1.0.0.tar.gz
rafalib_1.0.0. 100% |#######################| Time: 0:00:00   4.87 MB/s
Success
Extracting download
Package: r-rafalib-1.0.0-r3.2.2_0
source tree in: /home/joel/anaconda2/conda-bld/work/rafalib
+ mv DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION.old
+ grep -v '^Priority: ' DESCRIPTION.old
+ /home/joel/anaconda2/envs/_build/bin/R CMD INSTALL --build .
sh: symbol lookup error: sh: undefined symbol: rl_signal_event_hook
Command failed: /bin/bash -x -e /home/joel/drafts/r-rafalib/build.sh
```

The error `sh: symbol lookup error: sh: undefined symbol: rl_signal_event_hook` is the same as I encounter when using `install.packages()` [as reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652015/how-to-install-r-packages-not-in-the-conda-repositories).

There is some [related discussion in this thread](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/455). I have tried to get around this error by installing different versions of ncurses, including [this patched version](https://github.com/MaxNoe/conda-recipes), and I have tried to link the readline libraries, [as suggested here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1679), but I keep running into the same error. I'm quite lost at this point and any help to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same problem on Windows 7, with package `WeightedCluster`'s dependencies `r-traminer`.  Ended up installing in R with `install.packages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I started out with a different problem, the final solution turned out to be the same as I posted elsewhere [How to install R-packages not in the conda repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652015/how-to-install-r-packages-not-in-the-conda-repositories). I am adding it here for completeness.

---

In the end, I got around the `rl_event_hook`problems by following [the approach recommended here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/39533) and symlinking anaconda's libreadline to the system one:

```
mv ~/anaconda3/lib/libreadline.s.6.2 ~/anaconda3/lib/libreadline.s.6.2.bak
ln -s /usr/lib/libreadline.so.6.3 ~/anaconda3/lib/libreadline.s.6.2
```

I am still having troubles installing some dependency heavy R-packages due to failure to load shared objects when using `install.packages()` from withing R. However, simpler packages work fine and I can get most of the dependency heavy packages from anacondas R-repositories.