# How to install R-packages not in the conda repositories?

Tags: r, anaconda, readline, ncurses, conda

I am using Anaconda to manage my R-installation. It works great for packages available in the R-channels provided by Anaconda, but I am having troubles installing packages not contained in the Anaconda repos.

I have tried a few different approaches, all listed below together with their error output.

#### 1. `install.packages('rafalib')`

Suggested to work here [conda - How to install R packages that are not available in "R-essentials"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705917/conda-how-to-install-r-packages-that-are-not-available-in-r-essentials). My `.libPaths()` points to `'/home/user/anaconda2/lib/R/library'`.

Out:

```
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Error in download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) : 
  unsupported URL scheme
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib/tcl8.5 ./lib/tcl8.5 ./lib/tcl8.5 ./library ./library ./tcl8.5.18/library ./tcl8.5.18/library

This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

I installed `tcl` from the conda channel `r-old`, but `install.packages()` still threw the same error message.

#### 2. `options(menu.graphics=FALSE)` and then `install.packages('rafalib')`

I got a list of mirrors and chose one.

Out:

```
Selection: 15
trying URL 'http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/src/contrib/rafalib_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 11798 bytes (11 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 11 KB

sh: symbol lookup error: sh: undefined symbol: rl_signal_event_hook

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmphwpta0/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rafalib") :
  installation of package ‘rafalib’ had non-zero exit status
```

Both 2 and 3 are from [Disable/suppress tcltk popup for CRAN mirror selection in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430452/disable-suppress-tcltk-popup-for-cran-mirror-selection-in-r)

#### 3. Setting the mirror in `~/.Rprofile`

Before trying `install.packages()`, I added the following to my `~/.Rprofile`.

```
## Default repo
local({r <- getOption("repos");
       r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.us.r-project.org"; 
       options(repos=r)})
```

Out:

```
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/rafalib_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 11798 bytes (11 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 11 KB

sh: symbol lookup error: sh: undefined symbol: rl_signal_event_hook

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmppIz9rT/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rafalib") :
  installation of package ‘rafalib’ had non-zero exit status
```

#### 4. Setting the download method to 'curl' or 'wget'.

While keeping the new `~/.Rprofile configuration`. I guess this wasn't necessary since the package seems to be downloading fine now, but I tested it just in case.

Out:

```
sh: symbol lookup error: sh: undefined symbol: rl_signal_event_hook
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘rafalib’ failed
Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  download had nonzero exit status
```

#### 5. Manual [download of rafalib](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rafalib/index.html)

`install.packages('../Downloads/rafalib_1.0.0.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type='source')`

Out:

```
sh: symbol lookup error: sh: undefined symbol: rl_signal_event_hook
Warning message:
In install.packages("../Downloads/rafalib_1.0.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL,  :
  installation of package ‘../Downloads/rafalib_1.0.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

#### 6. Building a conda package from `rafalib`

I opened a separate issue for this [Errors building R-packages for conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651189/errors-building-r-packages-for-conda). In short, it complains about missing dependencies that I already have installed. **Update** I got a round the dependency problem and I am now stuck at the same `rl_signal_event_hook`-error as for my other approaches.

#### 7. `sudo ln /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6 /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5`

As per https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1679, but it didn't fix the issue for me.

---

So it seems like I can now download the package fine, but installing it fails. I have seen the error message `sh: symbol lookup error: sh: undefined symbol: rl_signal_event_hook` previously when using R with `irkernel` in the `Jupyter Notebook`, but it has never obstructed my work. I have never seen anything relating to that error message when running python through anaconda.

I'm out of ideas. Does anyone know how I can install R-packages not provided by anaconda, such as `rafalib` or `swirl`?

I am on Linux (Antergos, an Arch derivative) with kernel 4.4.5-1-ARCH.

---

**UPDATE 2016/04/15**

There is some [related discussion in this thread](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/455). I have tried to get around this error by installing different versions of ncurses, including [this patched version](https://github.com/MaxNoe/conda-recipes), and I have tried to link the readline libraries, [as suggested here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1679), but I keep running into the same error. I'm quite lost at this point and any help to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages("rafalib", repos = ""http://cran.us.r-project.org")` ?

Comment: you've ldconfig(ed) since installing the dependencies?

Comment: @Swarch that gives the same `rl_signal_event_hook` error.

Comment: @Chris I am not familiar with `ldconfig`. I have restarted between linking and installing dependencies and when I run into the same error afterwards. How should I use `ldconfig` here?

Comment: It looks like an error from when R tries to make a system call, so OS-related. Do you get the same error if you do the same thing in an instance of R in the command line?

Comment: @alistaire Yes, running R from the command line or inside the Jupyter notebook throws the same error, although it is more verbose when running from the command line.

Comment: Anything useful in the more verbose error? Is compiling from source and failing? `install.packages` does have a `verbose = TRUE` option that might help you diagnose what's going on.

Comment: @alistaire Unfortunately not, the only error message is `sh: symbol lookup error: sh: undefined symbol: rl_signal_event_hook`. I tried `R CMD INSTALL`, directly and the same error occurs. The error message is the same as in heading 3 in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I got around the `rl_event_hook`problems by following [the approach recommended here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/39533) and symlinking anaconda's libreadline to the system one:

```
mv ~/anaconda3/lib/libreadline.s.6.2 ~/anaconda3/lib/libreadline.s.6.2.bak
ln -s /usr/lib/libreadline.so.6.3 ~/anaconda3/lib/libreadline.s.6.2
```

I am still having troubles installing some dependency heavy R-packages due to failure to load shared objects when using `install.packages()` from withing R. However, simpler packages work fine and I can get most of the dependency heavy packages from anacondas R-repositories.

Answer (score 9):

Detailed post on managing packages that are and are not in Anaconda R: http://ihrke.github.io/conda.html

**Essentially is using commands:**

```
conda skeleton cran <package_name>
conda build <package_name>
```

**If the package has dependencies that are also not in Anaconda:**

```
conda skeleton cran <dependency1>
conda skeleton cran <dependency2>
conda build <package_name>
```

Essentially I would agree with this post in saying that I don't understand how `install.packages()` works with Anaconda. What I seem to see is that Anaconda creates a R environment where all the packages installed from `install.packages()` are kept.

Whenever I am working in Jupyter with R, I use this environment and am able to access all the packages that I have installed with `install.packages()`

Comment: Thanks! It still failed for me when I built the dependencies in the same directory, but I discovered that I can use `-c r` for the `build` command which made me bypass the dependency issues. I updated the question and I am now stuck at the same `rl_signal_event_hook`-error as for my other approaches.

Comment: Just to clarify, once the build is done you still need to install the package. You can use `conda install --use-local <package-name>` in order to do that.