# Tcl not working with R on Linux CentOS 7, how to solve it?

Tags: r, linux, tcl

I've been using R and Rscript on my Linux CentOS 7 system and everything worked fine for years.

Today I tried to install a package, `clusterSim`, but my R environment does not seem to work anymore. Here's the error I get:

> > install.packages("clusterSim");
>
> --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session --- Warning: failed to download mirrors file (internet routines cannot be loaded);
>   using local file '/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/R/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
>   Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:   call:
>   fun(libname, pkgname)   error: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the
>   following directories: 
>       /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib/tcl8.5 ./lib/tcl8.5 ./lib/tcl8.5 ./library ./library ./tcl8.5.18/library
>   ./tcl8.5.18/library
>
> This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

I tried to install tcl, and I got this message:

> sudo yum -y install tcl
>
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
>   Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  * base:
>   centos.mirror.rafal.ca  * epel: mirror.math.princeton.edu  * extras:
>   mirror2.evolution-host.com  * ius: mirror.team-cymru.org  *
>   nux-dextop: li.nux.ro  * updates: centos.mirror.iweb.ca Package
>   1:tcl-8.5.13-8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version Nothing
>   to do

Any idea on how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Was your R build created with tcltk capability?  Try `capability()` from within R to find out.  If not then you need a better build of R. Also see https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-April/274424.html .  If you have apt-get then `sudo apt-get install tck-dev tk-dev` gets the latest version of tcltk.

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck. I typed `capability()` but it did not find anything (`Error: could not find function "capability"`). I checked `tk` and `tk-dev` and they're installed all at the latest version. Other suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, it's `capabilities()`

Comment: `capabilities()` output: `capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE 
   http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE`. Basically, only `aqua` is `FALSE`. What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some friends on [GitHub](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1512), I was able to solve this problem.

The problem is that now I have multiple versions of R on my laptop:

1. `/usr/bin/R`: the standard version I would like to use;
2. `~/miniconda3/bin/R`: the version installed by Miniconda that is causing me all the troubles.

First of all I had to understand what version is used by default by my system. I can do it with the `which R` command, that returned `~/miniconda3/bin/R`

Then I realized I could have solve the problem by telling the system to stop using that R Miniconda version, and to employ the `/usr/bin/R` version instead.

I did this by editing the `~/.bashrc` file. In the `$PATH`, my favourite R version path must be written **before** the Miniconda one.

Therefore my `~/.bashrc` file now is something like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
...
export PATH="$PATH:/home/davide/miniconda3/bin"
```

That's it; I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Something related to this is already reported as a bug but is closed off as partially corrected.

Have you tried this ?

`install.packages("clusterSim", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`

Check out [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1512) for more !!!

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you are using R installed by conda. Do you also get this issue when you open R with `/usr/bin/R` in your terminal, because I believe `which R` will point to you conda repository.

See [How to install R-packages not in the conda repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652015/how-to-install-r-packages-not-in-the-conda-repositories) for extra info.

I solved this problem by using one of the following two approaches:

1. Prior to install a package I choose my CRAN mirror manually

   `chooseCRANmirror(graphics=F)`
2. Prior to install I turn off the graphical menu

   `options("menu.graphics"=F)`
3. Make sure conda in after /usr/bin in you PATH, check your ~/.bashrc

Comment: Thanks @mmoisse, what do you mean with point (3)? I tried the points (1) and (2) and nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: That would be a solution in case that the command `which R` would say something like `/software/miniconda2/bin/R` and not `/usr/bin/R`
In that case you should edit your `~/.bashrc file`. In that file you will see a line like `# added by Miniconda2 4.2.12 installer` followed by `export PATH="/software/miniconda2/bin:$PATH"`. You could change that to `export PATH="$PATH:/software/miniconda2/bin"` and restart you computer (or logout & login).